# Javascript internationalize my website (multilingual)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, multilingual

I'm making a website and my main framework is AngularJs.
At the moment my site is in italian but I'd like it to be multilingual (in particular italian and english).

The idea of the website is I have a index.html where I include all the content in this way:

```
<div ng-include="'it/menu.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'it/description.html'"></div>
...
```

where, obviously, into menu.html there will be the menu items and into description.html there will be the description. 
Since they are into the folder named "it", they are all in italian. 
I'm making another folder called "en" where there will be the same files but with english content and I would like to make a javascript such that if I click on Italian flag, I will have all my content in "it" folder, and if I click on the English flag, all the content into "en" folder.

Do you have any idea how to do it?

(If you have a better solution for multilingual website, are well accepted)

Answer (score 0):

Get the value of Current language By This javascript

```
var lang = document.documentElement.lang;
```

and use this 'lang' variable to direct the links of definite language folder

example :

```
    <div ng-include="'it/<value of lang here>/menu.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'it/<value of lang here>/description.html'"></div>
```

Hope it will help !

Comment: I'm tryin to do this but I don't understand how it's supposed to be. I mean: I have my `$scope.language=document.documentElement.lang;`; now, the directory is content/it/description.html. But if I do: `<div ng-include="'content/{{language}}/description.html'"></div>` it doesn't work

Comment: try to debug put the first line in after jquery in header